# Then I should not see (Cucumber)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am trying to use Cucumber to check a filter feature on a web page. If I check specific movie ratings, then it should only show those movies with those ratings in the table. Here is my scenario:

```
When I check the following ratings: 'PG', 'R'
And I press Refresh
Then I should not see /PG/
```

And here is my step definition:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should not see \/([^\/]*)\/$/ do |regexp|
  regexp = Regexp.new(regexp)
  if page.respond_to? :should
    page.should have_no_xpath('//*', :text => regexp)
  else
    assert page.has_no_xpath?('//*', :text => regexp)
  end
end
```

But I am getting an "Ambiguous match" error.

Here is some of the HTML in case it's important:

```
  <table id='movies'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Movie Title</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Release Date</th>
        <th>More Info</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Aladdin</td>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>1992-11-25 00:00:00 UTC</td>
        <td><a href="/movies/1">More about Aladdin</a></td>
      </tr>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Best title ever.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the steps you have defined here as such, but that you have defined a step elsewhere that conflicts with one of these. You should either reuse that step if it makes sense here or create a step that doesn't conflict.

Answer (score 0):

As michaeltwofish said. You probably have a step defined that does the same thing. Try removing one of the steps.

If you have duplicate methods/definitions. Meaning a definition with "And" and another definition with "Then" that does the same thing count as the same method.

And/When/Then/Given are basically the same thing. They server only to make the user story flow im a much more readable manor

Hope this additional info helped.